# Can't connect to mongoose/mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

When I'm trying to add an item to my database I get the following error on the terminal:

```
const serverSelectionError = new ServerSelectionError();
                               ^

MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at Connection.openUri (C:\Users\88cro\Desktop\blog\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:825:32)
    at C:\Users\88cro\Desktop\blog\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:417:10
    at C:\Users\88cro\Desktop\blog\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\88cro\Desktop\blog\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\88cro\Desktop\blog\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1270:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\88cro\Desktop\blog\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:416:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\88cro\Desktop\blog\server.js:6:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 162133351,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (C:\Users\88cro\Desktop\blog\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:387:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\88cro\Desktop\blog\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:310:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1284:16) {
            errno: -4078,
            code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '::1',
            port: 27017
          },
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}

Node.js v19.0.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I have MongoDB Atlas and mongoshell installed and running but that doesn't seem to fix the problem.
This is how I setup express and mongoose, I tried to change the url in mongoose.connect but it doesn't seem to work

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const articleRouter = require('./routes/articles')
const app = express()

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/blog', {useNewUrlParser: true})

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const articles = [{
        title: 'Test title',
        createdAt: new Date(),
        description: 'Test description'
    }]
    res.render('articles/index', { articles: articles })
})

app.use('/articles', articleRouter)

app.listen(5000)
```

Any ideas about how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: "MongoDB Atlas" is the MongoDB **cloud** service, but you try to connect to **localhost**.  So, it is not really clear what you try to achieve.

Comment: Are you meaning a running version of mongodb on your computer? Because that it what your code is trying to connect to rather than MongoDB Atlas (which is a hosted service). If you're working on your local machine, can you connect using Compass? Can you run any commands from your mongoshell? Normally if you run the `mongo` command, it will tell you connection string. Show us that first please.